# Need some assistance on a DBF "File not found" error in Python when looping through a directory?

Tags: python, for-loop, file-conversion

I would like to ask for help with a Python script that is supposed to loop through a directory on a drive. Basically, what I want to do is convert over 10,0000 DBF files to CSV. So far, I can achieve this on an individual *dbf* file by using using the *dbfread* and *Pandas* packages. Running this script over 10,000 individual times is obviously not feasible, hence why I want automate the task by writing a script that will loop through each *dbf* file in the directory.

Here is what I would like to do.

- Define the directory
- Write a for loop that will loop through each file in the directory
- Only open a file with the extension '.dbf'
- Convert to Pandas DataFrame
- Define the name for the output file
- Write to CSV and place file in a new directory

Here is the code that I was using to test whether I could convert an individual '.dbf' file to a CSV.

```
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd

table = DBF('Name_of_File.dbf')

#I originally kept receiving a unicode decoding error
#So I manually adjusted the attributes below

table.encoding = 'utf-8' # Set encoding to utf-8 instead of 'ascii'

table.char_decode_errors = 'ignore' #ignore any decode errors while reading in the file

frame  = pd.DataFrame(iter(table)) #Convert to DataFrame

print(frame) #Check to make sure Dataframe is structured proprely 

frame.to_csv('Name_of_New_File')
```

The above code worked exactly as it was intended.

Here is my code to loop through the directory.

```
import os
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd

directory = 'Path_to_diretory'

dest_directory = 'Directory_to_place_new_file'

for file in os.listdir(directory):

    if file.endswith('.DBF'):
        print(f'Reading in {file}...')
        dbf = DBF(file)
        dbf.encoding = 'utf-8'
        dbf.char_decode_errors = 'ignore'
        print('\nConverting to DataFrame...')
        frame = pd.DataFrame(iter(dbf))
        print(frame)
        outfile = frame.os.path.join(frame + '_CSV' + '.csv')
        print('\nWriting to CSV...')
        outfile.to_csv(dest_directory, index = False)
        print('\nConverted to CSV. Moving to next file...')

    else:
        print('File not found.')
```

When I run this code, I receive a *DBFNotFound* error that says it couldn't find the first file in the directory. As I am looking at my code, I am not sure why this is happening when it worked in the first script.

This is the code from the *dbfread* package from where the exception is being raised.

```
 class DBF(object):
   """DBF table."""
    def __init__(self, filename, encoding=None, ignorecase=True,
             lowernames=False,
             parserclass=FieldParser,
             recfactory=collections.OrderedDict,
             load=False,
             raw=False,
             ignore_missing_memofile=False,
             char_decode_errors='strict'):

        self.encoding = encoding
        self.ignorecase = ignorecase
        self.lowernames = lowernames
        self.parserclass = parserclass
        self.raw = raw
        self.ignore_missing_memofile = ignore_missing_memofile
        self.char_decode_errors = char_decode_errors

        if recfactory is None:
            self.recfactory = lambda items: items
        else:
            self.recfactory = recfactory

    # Name part before .dbf is the table name
        self.name = os.path.basename(filename)
        self.name = os.path.splitext(self.name)[0].lower()
        self._records = None
        self._deleted = None

        if ignorecase:
            self.filename = ifind(filename)
        if not self.filename:
            **raise DBFNotFound('could not find file {!r}'.format(filename))** #ERROR IS HERE
        else:
            self.filename = filename
```

Thank you any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir` returns the file names *inside* the directory, so you have to join them to the base path to get the full path:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
    if file_name.endswith('.DBF'):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
        print(f'Reading in {file_name}...')
        dbf = DBF(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to clarify, am I substituting 'os.listdir(directory)' with 'os.path.join(directory, file) in the for loop?

Comment: `for file in os.path.join(directory, file):` says the variable file is not defined and returns what is in my else statement instead.

Comment: If think you misunderstood - please check the edited answer